# How do I change my skin in Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

So its tells me to go to different websites and it still doesn't let me change my skin i'm on Bedrock Minecraft and on Nintendo Switch but this happens and i'm also new to Minecraft can anyone help me?[image]

Comment: you have to be on the actual game, i believe switch actually doesnt support custom skins, only marketplace skins

Comment: oh okay thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Nintendo switch doesn't actually allow you to make custom skins, but it does allow you to buy different things from the marketplace to customize your character. To do this, buy some mine-coins, head over to the button that says "Profile" and then you can customize your character by pressing "Edit" on the character you want to edit. You can change skin color, height, hair color, and other things like that, as well as buying different clothes and using them. There are also free things, so if you don't want to buy anything, you could just use those free items.